# Trouble with"onmouseover" event using native Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent, onmouseout

I am attempting to add an `onmouseout` function to the names in the following widget. The `onmouseover` works fine but the `onmouseout` fires almost immediately on rollover. Not sure why.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8fmg/

I think it may have something to do "bubbling" and I have been trying to read about the subject but don't quite understand the implications.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have an unbalanced `<head>` tag, could you also post in your question relevant code where you problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Your mouseover handler is destroying the `<a>` which the handlers are attached to. Adjust your code so that the handlers are attached to a permanent element, either by attaching to a different element or not destroying the one you are using.

Comment: but I have hard coded the onmouseover function ... would it still be destroyed?

Comment: the actual function in the Book object still exists, but the element it is assigned to is gone. I guess `onmouseout` fires as a side effect of the element disappearing underneath your mouse.